# How to do 2 way communication between 2 different subnets?

Tags: networking, network-programming, router, vlan

I am sort of stumped on this.

My layout will be the following:

one subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 whereas each computer on that subnet has 2 interfaces and it is statically assigned. GW will be a router with DHCP/DNS disabled at 192.168.0.254.

The second interface will have a subnet based on the last digit of the statically assigned first subnet whereas:
NIC1: 192.168.0.1 NIC2: 192.168.1.1 (255.255.255.0)
NIC1: 192.168.0.2 NIC2: 192.168.2.1 (255.255.255.0)
and so on.

On Nic2 will be running a software DHCP server.

My issue is this: I want all computers on all the NIC2 subnets to communicate to the master subnet of 192.168.0.X, and vice versa.

What is the best way to do this? Additionally the hardware MUST be configurable via REST or otherwise. So I cannot really hookup a router with static routes for each one of these because that's not really configurable programmatically. I CAN however use managed switches for this since CISCO makes a rather cheap managed switch that handles REST API requests.

I have considered bridging NIC 1 and NIC 2 but the issue is I would need to block DHCP packets from leaving the NIC 2 network. This doesn't seem possible with the limited windows network bridge.

Open to any suggestions!

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to configure your gateway (router) with a static route from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.2.0 and from 192.168.2.0 to 192.168.1.0. You don't say what kind of router you are using, but at least on Cisco, it IS possible to configure a static route via REST (as well as other ways). Refer to http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/aci/apic/sw/1-x/mapping/mapping_gd/layer3_examples.html#pgfId-1092835 .

Comment: Link is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 answers to this.

The first is what Herb said above which is to use Cisco smart switches and REST queries.

The second which is what I in the end implemented was to use a windows server environment with RRAS Lan-Lan routing. The details of which can be found here: https://onlize.wordpress.com/2012/08/18/lan-routing-on-windows-server-2008r2-step-by-step/